# unexpected error during installing the mean stack

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, bash

i'm trying to install the mean stack on windows xp with git bash.
I downloaded the zip from [mean.io](http://www.mean.io/), and when i launch the 'npm install' on the directory of the mean stack i occurr to this error althought i followed all istructions of mean.io:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.4-preview20130916)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

corsojava@YKLW101934 ~
$ cd /c/ms-application/mean-stack

corsojava@YKLW101934 /c/ms-application/mean-stack
$ pwd
/c/ms-application/mean-stack

corsojava@YKLW101934 /c/ms-application/mean-stack
$ npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-bower-task
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/supertest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-flash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/should
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-local
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-facebook
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-twitter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-github
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-google-oauth
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/view-helpers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mean-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-nodemon
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-concurrent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-mocha-test
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-bower-task
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/supertest
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-flash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/should
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-local
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-facebook
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-twitter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-github
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-google-oauth
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/view-helpers
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mean-logger
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-nodemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-concurrent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-mocha-test

> mean@1.0.0 postinstall c:\ms-application\mean-stack
> node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt install

Running "bower:install" (bower) task
bower not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#2.3.2
bower resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#2.3.2
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.0.6
bower resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.0.6
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.0.6
bower resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.0.6
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.0.6
bower resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.0.6
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#~0.4.0
bower resolve git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#~0.4.0
bower not-cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#0.0.4
bower resolve git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#0.0.4
bower not-cached git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.4
bower resolve git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.4
bower not-cached git://github.com/components/jquery.git#~1.9.1
bower resolve git://github.com/components/jquery.git#~1.9.1
Fatal error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular-cookies.git", exit code of #128
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0

corsojava@YKLW101934 /c/ms-application/mean-stack
$
```

"Fatal error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular-cookies.git", exit code of #128
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0"

any ideas?

Comment: Have you retried the command? The error appears to be network or service (GitHub) based and may have been temporary.

Comment: i tried more times the same command and sometimes changed the github url

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bitnami MEAN stack, which provides open source installer, VM and cloud images for Windows, Linux Mac http://bitnami.com/stack/mean  (disclaimer, I am one of the developers). It will allow you to install and configure MongoDB, Node, etc.